# Searching a matrix and deleting vectors that transpose to each other except for the first (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

In Matlab...

Here is a sample from a larger matrix:

```
 5    11     9    12
 5    11    12     9
 5     9    11    12
 5     9    12    11
 5    12     9    11
 5    12    11     9
12    11     9     7
12    11     7     9
12     9    11     7
12     9     7    11
12     7     9    11
12     7    11     9
11    12     9     7
11    12     7     9
11     9    12     7
11     9     7    12
11     7     9    12
11     7    12     9
 9    11    12     7
 9    11     7    12
 9    12    11     7
 9    12     7    11
 9     7    12    11
 9     7    11    12
 7    11     9    12
 7    11    12     9
 7     9    11    12
 7     9    12    11
 7    12     9    11
 7    12    11     9
```

I'd like some code that will look through this matrix and find all of the vectors that transpose to each other, e.g.

```
7    12     9    11
```

and

```
6    11     8    10
```

and create a new matrix that contains only one version for each of the transposing vectors, in its lowest transposition available on the original matrix (i.e. if the original matrix contained:

```
7    12     9    11
```

and

```
6    11     8    10
```

Then I would only want to keep

```
6    11     8    10
```

(Similarly I'd like the list to keep any vectors for which there are no transpositions)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what do you mean by `vectors that transpose to each other`?

Comment: Agreed.  It's unclear what the implied relationship is between those two example vectors.

Comment: Sorry - each figure in the second is one integer less than in the first one. Another vector that i would describe as transposed, would be: 9 14  11  13  - how should I have described this?

Comment: Start with `N=bsxfun(@minus,M(:,1),M)` to get a matrix where the rows which you call transposed are equal, then use `unique` to identify the rows which are transposed to each other `[~,~,index]=unique(N,'rows')`

Comment: Thank you - I'm struggling to make the... 

[~,~,index]=unique(N,'rows') 

...stage work... could you make that a bit more dunce proof? All i've done currently is copy and paste that line in - should I have changed parts of it (apologies for general stupidity...)

Comment: (The first bit you've sent me works though!)

Comment: @SamLeak - I don't know, but transpose has a specific meaning when it comes to matrices, and this is not it!

Comment: Sorry Oliver - I shouldn't have used that word then, you'll have to trust me that it can mean that in other contexts! Daniel - any further thoughts on `[~,~,index]=unique(N,'rows')`  ?

Comment: @Daniel - Thank you - I'm struggling to make the... `[~,~,index]=unique(N,'rows')` ...stage work... could you make that a bit more dunce proof? All i've done currently is copy and paste that line in - should I have changed parts of it (apologies for general stupidity...) - (The first bit you've sent me works though!)

Comment: @SamLeak: Take a simple example like `N=[11 13 19 11 13].'` Using unique you will get the same number labelled to identical numbers, in this case `1` to `11`, `2` to `13`.

Comment: Thanks for that @Daniel . So unique seems to make sense: if I use `N=[11 13 19 11 13]` and then try `unique(N)` then it returns only the unique values `[11 13 19]` . For a Matrix 'A,' then to return the unique rows you should be able to use `unique(A,'rows')`.   As such i think my problem seems to be with the `bsxfun(@minus,M(:,1),M)` part of the process (for Matrix 'M').  I'm not sure that this is doing what we're hoping (for each row, subtracting the value in its first column from every value (e.g. for `[8 8 2 1]` you would subtract 8 from each value, becoming `[ 0 0 -6 -7]`) ?

Comment: @Daniel - I've just realised that `[~,~,index]=unique(N,'rows')` is indexing - a bit slow on the uptake, given that it includes the word 'index' ...apologies. For the second issue, it seems that this should work: `B=M-repmat(M(:,1),1,size(M,2))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `A` as the input array, here's one *loopy* approach -

```
out = [];
A_cut = A;
while size(A_cut,1)~=0
    grp_mask = all(diff(bsxfun(@minus,A_cut,A_cut(1,:)),[],2)==0,2)
    grpIDs = find(grp_mask)
    [~,min_idx] = min(A_cut(grpIDs,1))
    out_add = A_cut(grpIDs(min_idx),:)
    out = [out ; out_add];
    A_cut = A_cut(~grp_mask,:)
end
```

Sample input, output -

```
A =
     9     9     3     2
     5    10     7     9
     5    11     9    12
     6    11     8    10
    12    11     9     7
     7    12     9    11
     8     8     2     1
out =
     8     8     2     1 %// replaces (8,8,2,1) & (9,9,3,2)
     5    10     7     9 %// replaces (5,10,7,9),(6,11,8,10) & (7,12,9,11)
     5    11     9    12
    12    11     9     7
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for that! I'm not convinced it's worked (but I could be being dense) - here's the code I'm using with your bit plugged in: 

`clear 
clc 

v = [ 0 2 4 5 7 9 11 12 ]; 
n = 4; 

allSets = nchoosek(v,n); 

output = arrayfun(@(x) perms(allSets(x,:)),1:size(allSets,1),'Uni',0) 

A = vertcat(output{:}) 

out = []; 
A_cut = A; 

while size(A_cut,1)~=0 
grp_mask = all(diff(bsxfun(@minus,A_cut,A_cut(1,:)),[],2)==0,2) 
grpIDs = find(grp_mask) 
[~,min_idx] = min(A_cut(grpIDs,1)) 
out_add = A_cut(grpIDs(min_idx),:) 
out = [out ; out_add]; 
A_cut = A_cut(~grp_mask,:) 
end`

What do you think?

Comment: Hey @SamLeak! So, is there a wrong row in the output `out` with that sample input?

Comment: Actually, on checking, my problem was with another part of the code - sorry about that! So @divakar your answer actually worked perfectly - thank you! Do you know how I might, following this, then subtract from each value, in a given row, the value in the first column of that row, (such that each row begins with the value 0) ? E.g., for `[8 8 2 1]` you would subtract 8 from each value, becoming `[ 0 0 -6 -7]`, and `[ 5 10 7 9]` you would subtract 5 from each value, becoming `[ 0 5 2 4 ]` ? Thanks again!

Comment: @divikar - With help from a friend, it appears that this should do the trick: `starting_on_zero=out-repmat(out(:,1),1,size(out,2))`